# DB2 Z/OS : Find missing data in table

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, zos

I have a list of tables and I want to find out the missing tables in db2 Z/OS.

I can think of using CTE with hardcoded values(UNION ALL) and then performing a LEFT OUTER JOIN on catalog table.

Not sure how to hardcode the values in CTE. Is there any other faster way to query the existence of tables as I have a huge list of tables that needs to be checked.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Load your huge list into some intermediate table, let's say with (CREATOR VARCHAR(128), NAME VARCHAR(128)) fields.
As for hardcoded values. Try this:

```
select v.*
from (
select 'SYSIBM', 'SYSTABLES' from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
select 'SYSIBM', 'SYSCOLUMNSS' from sysibm.sysdummy1
-- union all
--select ...
) v (creator, name)
where not exists (
select 1 
from sysibm.systables t 
where t.creator=v.creator and t.name=v.name
);
```

You can use some text processing utilities like sed to produce the strings like:

```
select 'SYSIBM', 'SYSTABLES' from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
```

from those found in your input file:

```
SYSIBM,SYSTABLES
```

You can do some minimal changes to the results of such a processing to construct the final statement like above. But it's not for really huge number of tables, of course...